Max amplitude of superposition of 2 waves
Find amplitude of superposition of 2 waves, $4.6\sin (2\pi\cdot 5.4x)$ and $3.2\sin(2\pi\cdot 10x)$,
My answer is simply $4.6+ 3.2 = 7.8m$ , correct me if I am  wrong.
If it's $4.6\cos(2\pi\cdot 5.4x)$ and $3.2\sin(2\pi\cdot 10x)$,
then the max amplitude should be $\sqrt{4.6^2 + 3.2^2} = 5.6m$, correct me if I am wrong.

Aren't each of those waves going to grow in amplitude at a constant rate with increasing x?

@Transistor, not , they are not at the same frequency, so , it cant be simply adding up IMO. I am not sure which is correctc though.

$4.6sin(2π \times 5.4x)$ is radically different to $4.6sin(2π)∗5.4x$. I think you need to clarify in your question.

@Transistor, it's clearly sin (2x3.142 x 5.4x)

It is in your comment. It's not in the question. Note that Eduardo's answer has to use both interpretations as the equations are not clear.

7.8m would be correct.  Visualized.

Here's the 2 waveforms, as you can see the peaks of each never line up in a brief time period like the one shown, but eventually they will. Hence 7.8 is the right answer, practically. You can probably figure out when exactly using modulo (aka clock) arithmetic.

One approach to find when it peaks is to differentiate the summed waves with respect to time, and look at where that is 0, ie the peak or trough of the original function.
d/dt(4.6 sin(2 π×5.4 t) + 3.2 sin(2 π×10 t)) = 156.074 cos(33.9292 t) + 201.062 cos(62.8319 t)
so you want to solve for t in 156.074 cos(33.9292 t) + 201.062 cos(62.8319 t)=0
...which i can't.
However running a search I get the following runs, as you can see the improvement in approaching 7.80 is a slow business
-------------------------
improvement = 7.7856
bestA = 7.7856
bestt = 1.5258
-------------------------
improvement = 0.012792
bestA = 7.7984
bestt = 2.8247
-------------------------
improvement = 1.7764e-15
bestA = 7.7984
bestt = 7.8247
-------------------------
improvement = 2.6645e-15
bestA = 7.7984
bestt = 22.825
-------------------------

...etc even after 1e6 seconds it still hasn't changed from 7.7984

The first two maxima are shown here, identified with faint x and o. The search algorithm only looks at areas where the two sin waves are near 1, that's why the first three maxima are ignored.

Thanks, can i say that for any superposition of sine / cos surve ( sine + sine ) or ( cos + cos) that are not in the same frequency , the amplitude of 2 waves is just simply sum up of amplitude of both waves ?

For superposition of sine curve/cos curve ( A cos wt + B sin wt) , the ampllitude of superposition of both curve is sqrt( A^2+ B^2) ?

comment 1 yes, but you might have to wait a long time. comment 2 ok, so they are at the same frequency? There's a trig formula for adding Bsin(x)+Acos(x) but I don't know it. The answer will be a single sin wave. https://www.cuemath.com/trigonometry/trigonometry-formula/ seems a pretty comprehensive list of identities.

If they are of the same frequency the amplitude of  ( A cos wt + B sin wt)  is sqrt( A^2+ B^2)  ? How if the frequency are not the same ? ( A cos w1t + B sin w2t), can i still say that amplitude of superposition of them is sqrt( A^2+ B^2) ?

If the frequencies are the same there is a trig identity for that but I don't know it. If the frequencies are different then the maximum amplitude will be A+B, eventually.

How about the superposition of 500 cos2pi()8.9t, 1000sin2pi()8.9t, 1500sin2pi()3t ? For me, i just add up the waves of the same frequency first, 500 cos2pi()8.9t, 1000sin2pi()8.9t, amplitude = sqrt( 500^2 + 1000^2) = 1118, Now whole equation becomees 1118 sin 2pi()(8.9t+  Φ ) , then I only add up 1500sin2pi()3t with 1118 sin 2pi()(8.9t+  Φ ) , that brings me to the amplitude of 1500+1118 = 2618, correct me if I am wrong.

Yes the first two combine to give a single sine wave at 8.9t with a phase angle, a cos x + b sin x can be written as R cos(x − α)
where
R =√(a^2+b^2)
tan α =b/a , from there on since the frequencies are different you can add the amplitude.

For, amplitude of superpostion of curve 1 sin 0.4pi()t + 2 cos0.6pi()t + 3 sin 0.8pi()t, can i simply say that the max amplitude would be 1+2+3=6 ? or sqrt ( (1+3)^2 + 2^2)=7.2 ?

I suggest you plot these curves out to reassure yourself, because they are all harmonics of 0.2 they will form a stable waveform whose shape is dependent on the phase angle between the three components.
